# which timezone does cron use on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, timezone

I need to run a cronjob at 21:02 GMT. My crontab is:

```
 CRON_TZ=GMT
 02 21 * * * thecommand
```

This works well on SuSE, but does not work on Ubuntu. Instead, it runs thecommand at 20:02, i.e. the timezone is chosen as GMT+1. Why?

The server timezone is MSK (now it is GMT+3).

From man 8 cron :
"The daemon will use, if present, the definition from /etc/timezone for the timezone"

```
 $cat /etc/timezone
 Europe/Moscow
```

The command lsb_release -a says:

```
 No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID: Ubuntu
 Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
 Release:        14.04
 Codename:       trusty
```

Answer (score 6):

The version of cron running on Ubuntu 14.04 has no support for `CRON_TZ`.  If you look at `man 5 crontab` locally on the Ubuntu box, you will see that the inability to change cron's timezone for scheduling purposes is called out as a limitation:

> LIMITATIONS
>
> The cron daemon runs with a defined timezone. It currently does not support per-user timezones. All  the  tasks:  system's  and
> user's  will  be run based on the configured timezone. Even if a user specifies the TZ environment variable in his crontab this
> will affect only the commands executed in the crontab, not the execution of the crontab tasks themselves.

So: you have to find out what time zone cron is using, and use that in your crontab.  You can do this automatically if you have a script generating the crontab. For example:

```
TZ=$(</etc/timezone) date +'%M %H' -d @$(date -ud '21:02' +%s)
```

On my system, `/etc/timezone` contains `America/New_York`, so the above command outputs `02 17` for what I should put in the first two fields of a crontab entry to get a job to run at 21:02 UTC. On your system, that file presumably contains `Europe/Moscow`, so the command would output `02 00` instead.